# Зайти на почту через Java

Tags: java

в общем пишу бота для множественного входа на почту (для себя). есть 300 почт, нужно поочередно на них заходить и выходить так, чтобы сервер понимал, что был произведен вход.

Нашел такой вот код в интернете:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws MessagingException {
       /* Properties properties = new Properties();
        //Хост или IP-адрес почтового сервера
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.ru");
        //Требуется ли аутентификация для отправки сообщения
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //Порт для установки соединения
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        //Фабрика сокетов, так как при отправке сообщения Yandex требует SSL-соединения
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        //Создаем соединение для отправки почтового сообщения
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                //Аутентификатор - объект, который передает логин и пароль
                new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("something.some.mail.ru", "dragon01");
                    }
                });

        //Создаем новое почтовое сообщение
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        //От кого
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("something.some.mail.ru"));
        //Кому
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("dgylagc007@gmail.com"));
        //Тема письма
        message.setSubject("Очень важное письмо!!!");
        //Текст письма
        message.setText("Hello, Email!");
        //Поехали!!!
        Transport.send(message);*/





        Properties props = new Properties();
        //настройки почтового сервера
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.mail.ru");
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.sendpartial", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        //создаем сообщения
        /*MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        //устанавливаем тему письма
        message.setSubject("тестовое письмо!");

        //указываем получателя
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("see574@yandex.ru"));

        //указываем дату отправления
        message.setSentDate(new Date());*/

        //логин и пароль
        String userLogin = "something.some@mail.ru";
        String userPassword = "password";

        //авторизируемся на сервере

               Transport transport = session.getTransport();
               transport.connect("smtp.mail.ru", 465, userLogin, userPassword);




        //отправляем сообщение
        //transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    }
}
```

в среде разработки все компилируется и пишет Process finished with exit code 0.

Запускают через командную строку и получаю:

```
C:\Users\Илья>java C:\Users\Илья\IdeaProjects\JavaComingMails\src\Main.java
C:\Users\╚ы№ \IdeaProjects\JavaComingMails\src\Main.java:5: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
                          ^
C:\Users\╚ы№ \IdeaProjects\JavaComingMails\src\Main.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void main(String args[]) throws MessagingException {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class MessagingException
  location: class Main
C:\Users\╚ы№ \IdeaProjects\JavaComingMails\src\Main.java:4: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.*;
^
C:\Users\╚ы№ \IdeaProjects\JavaComingMails\src\Main.java:6: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.*;
^
C:\Users\╚ы№ \IdeaProjects\JavaComingMails\src\Main.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        ^
  symbol:   class Session
  location: class Main
C:\Users\╚ы№ \IdeaProjects\JavaComingMails\src\Main.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
                          ^
  symbol:   variable Session
  location: class Main
C:\Users\╚ы№ \IdeaProjects\JavaComingMails\src\Main.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
               Transport transport = session.getTransport();
               ^
  symbol:   class Transport
  location: class Main
7 errors
error: compilation failed
```

т.к. начинающий не понял в чем проблема компиляции и подойдет ли вообще этот метод написания для такого бота.

Comment: У вас в classpath нет зависимости JavaMail.

Comment: Извиняюсь за нескромный вопрос, после Вашего комментария до сих пор гуглю и ничего толкового по поводу classpath не нашел, все по разному описывают что и куда надо добавить и надо ли вообще.Как сделал я - в переменных средах у меня есть JAVA_HOME, но не было вообще CLASSPATH, я собственно его создал и указал значение JAVA_HOME\lib, а JAVA_HOME ведет соответственно в jdk, но ничего в итоге все равно не работает, пытался писать в том числе в коммандной строке java -cp..., все тщетно. Не подскажите как это должно выглядеть правильно?

Comment: По какому учебнику вы изучали Java?

Comment: Я сейчас все еще читаю Шилдта java 8, но я до подобных тем не доходил, я пока что интерфейсы прошел.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но вроде java mail - это api javaee, и ни в каком даже jdk его нет. Надо найти и положить с свой classpath библиотеку java mail. Откуда она а idea-и пёс её знает. Но часто java-прожекты управляются maven-ом, который скачивает все необходимое из интернета. И при сборке прожекта настраивает classpath, указывающий на скачанное.

Comment: Большое спасибо, понял в какую сторону копать теперь)